# What options would load an escape character into Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Having a tough time playing with Redshift's `COPY` options to load a field that has an escape character immediately followed by a delimiter ('`|`'). Data looks like this:

```
00b9e290000f8350b9c780832a210000|MY DATA\|AB
```

So that has 3 fields that I'm trying to load. When I run with just ESCAPE, Redshift seems to properly add `\` to doubleescape, but then the pipe delimiter gets ignored. So Redshift ends up trying to load all of the following into the second field: `MY DATA|AB`. Error message is that the delimiter was not found, since that's read as the second field with no following delimiter

I've tried running COPY with just the `ESCAPE` option, the CSV + ESCAPE options and a few others with no luck. Is there anything else I should try? Or should I be adding some pre-process step to doubleescape?

Comment: Have you tried leaving the escape option off altogether?

Comment: Yep, I did and ran into an issue on another line... I resolved the issue by adding quotes in the step before running the COPY command

Comment: Anybody else finding there way here, look at this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42720342/escaping-delimiter-in-amazon-redshift-copy-command)